How to change data grid view cell value to null in int? typed cell
I am trying to make data grid view cell change its value to default when user enters invalid data. The cell type is int?.
I tried to do it with CellValidating event, it is possible to give number with DataGridView.EditingControl.Text = "0", but ig it is not possible to change cell value to null. But the column is binded to int? typed property. I also tried to do it with CellParsing event but this event fires after cell is validated, so if user enters empty value and hits enter, data grid view throws error because cell only takes int values, but I want it to change the value to null if user enters empty value.
private void DataGridView_NumberCellValidate(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e){
    if (e.ColumnIndex != 8 && e.ColumnIndex != 9) return;  
    if (!int.TryParse(e.FormattedValue?.ToString(), out int temp)) {
        e.Cancel = true;
        // i want to not cancel the endEdit, but change value to default if value is not valid
        MessageBox.Show("Value is not number."); 
}}


Maybe this Code Project question helps. See also DataGridViewCellStyle.NullValue Property.

The problem with the solution you provided with the link is that those events fire after validating event which gives dataError if you keep the cell empty, it does not recognize empty cell as a null it recognize it as a string.Empty and the column is binded to int so it fails to cast as i understand from my tests. And the nullValue property is what to show when cell is null, but cell becomes string.Empty rather than null.
